# Get plugin object reference back from element on which plugin is applied

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

Please consider following code. Here I have a jquery plugin `myPlugin` by using which I changed the ui of `#targetElement`

```
var myPluginVar = $('#targetElement').myPlugin();
```

I created a button and added a click event listener on it

```
$('#myButton').click(function(){
    // HERE I want reference of myPlugin back.
}
```

Now on a button trigger I want to get back `myPlugin` object.
I don't want to use `myPluginVar`. Is there any way to get reference of `myPlugin` using element on which plugin is applied.

Comment: The short answer is yes, but would need to see your widget code to understand more. Are you trying to determine the HTML Element that your plugin is being used upon or the selector?

Comment: Posting code will be appreciated 

    $('#myButton').click(function(){
 var newref = $('#targetElement').myPlugin; //reference of the function
    var newrefex = $('#targetElement').myPlugin();
}

Comment: That depends on your code. The plugin is probably setting its property in the element. Why can't you use global var `myPluginVar`?

Answer (score 3):

`$.fn.myPlugin = function(){}` will create a plugin that can be called on an element like this: `$("#example").myPlugin();`, as you know.

`$.myPlugin = function(){}` will create a plugin that can be called statically like this: `$.myPlugin();`.

So all you have to do is set `$.myPlugin` every time you call `$.fn.myPlugin` so it will refer to the last element used.

```js
$.fn.myPlugin = function(){
  this.text("Hello, world!");
  
  var t = this;
  
  $.myPlugin = function() {
    return t;
  }
};

$("#test").myPlugin();

$("#button").click(function(){
  $.myPlugin().text("something else");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">
</div>
<button id="button">Click Me</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

thats depend on how you write your plugins.

following this example of basic plugin:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.myPlugin = function(){
        return this.text('Iam is myPlugin');
    };
}(jQuery));
```

thats plugin (yet) cannot be referenced, because it didn't passed their self to anything.

but if change plugin code abbove to this:

```
(function($){
    $.myPlugin = function(el){
        $(el).data('myPlugin', this);
        return $(el).text('Iam is myPlugin');
    };
    $.fn.myPlugin = function(){
        return new $.myPlugin(this);
    };
}(jQuery));
```

you can call plugin self referenced with:

```
$('#targetElement').data('myPlugin');
```

offcourse if plugin never initialized on #targetElement, it will returned as *undefined*

but if you have initialize #targetElement, with:

```
$('#targetElement').myPlugin();
```

it will return with *$.myPlugin* object